# C++: Why does libtiff break the console-output?

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, cout, libtiff

So finally I’m not able to help myself out by researching anymore. Hopefully you can help me.
I recently decided to learn C++ in the context of my bachelor-thesis: My first aim is to read the pixel-values of a tiff-image with the libtiff-library. Yet, every call of a function of the library seems to break parts of my program.

---

Here’s the simple “HelloWorld”-Program, it works as it should:

```
#include "tiffio.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
//  TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("path to .tif", "r");
    return 0;
}
```

When I uncomment the second line in main(), the code still does compile without errors (except the warning that ‘tif’ isn’t used) and I can start the program as usual. Yet nothing gets printed into the console anymore. Not “Hello” nor any errors.

---

Any suggestions where the error could be? The code should be alright, I guess I messed something up during the setup of the library or so. Here’s what I did:

1. I managed to set up eclipse (Mars, 32bit) for C++ and MinGW (32bit) on my 64bit Win7, then downloaded libtiff 4.0.4 and built it following [this](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0/mingw_how_to.html#libtiff) instruction.
2. I created a new C++-project with the mentioned code and did the following adjustments in the project-properties:

   - Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Library
     Paths-> Added “D:/… /tiff-4.0.4/libtiff/.libs”
   - Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->MinGW C++
     Linker->Miscellaneous->Set Linkerflags to “-static-libgcc
     -static-libstdc++”
   - Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->MinGW C++ Linker->Libraries-> Set
     (-L) to “D:/… /tiff-4.0.4/libtiff/.libs” and (-l) to “libtiff”

I know the .tif is a valid file as I implemented parts of my program in C#, using the [LibTiff.NET](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library by BitMiracle.

Thank you in advance!

---

**Edit 1:** The same error occures, even if `TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("path to .tif", "r");` is never called but written down in a dead part of the code. Debugging does not work either, the program seems to be terminated (exit value 0) before a single line is executed, without any error-reports.

Comment: Well, either, 1) You built libtiff incorrectly.  2) Your main program is built with differing options than your libtiff library.  3) Libtiff has a bug in the first function call.  So take your pick.   Also, doing stuff like this for C++ takes a lot more experience to determine where errors are occurring than doing this in C# or .NET.  For example, you could have debugged into the TIFFOpen function to see exactly what line breaks your program within that function.

Comment: It might both be that libtiff is built incorrectly and the main problem is built with other options. Yet the linked [tutorial](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0/mingw_how_to.html#libtiff) was not too hard to follow. But I don't have the knowledge to tell. Debugging does not work, the program seems to be terminated before a single line is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to get rid of it.

I set up eclipse (Mars) for C++ and MinGW on my 64bit Win7, then downloaded libtiff 4.0.4 and built it following [this](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0/mingw_how_to.html#libtiff) instruction.
After the build, I got two directories containing files:

1. include

   - tiff.h
   - tiffconf.h
   - tiffio.h
   - tiffio.hxx
   - tiffvers.h
2. lib

   - libtiff.a
   - libtiff.dll.a
   - libtiff.la
   - libtiffxx.a
   - libtiffxx.dll.a
   - libtiffxx.la

I also linked **all include files** and only the **libtiff.a** to my project and that solved it, ie, the other lines are now executed.

I hope, I helped with this post.